# How to use styled components with Field from redux form and custom component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-form

I have something like this:

```js
const StyledField = styled(Field)`
  outline: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  border-radius: 3px;

  option {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
`;
```

```
 <StyledField
      options={options}
      additionalTooltipStyles={additionalTooltipStyles}
      name="targetPhase"
      component={SelectInput}
      placeholder={getMessage('details.edit.innovation.status.change.phase')}
      title={getMessage('details.edit.phase.change.innovation.form.tooltip.title')}
      description={getMessage('details.edit.phase.change.innovation.form.tooltip')}
      label={getMessage('details.edit.innovation.status.choose.phase.description')}
    />
```

and I've got an error:

```
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'PropsWithChildren<WrappedFieldProps>' is missing the following properties from type 'SelectInputT': description, label, options, title, and 3 more. [2322]
```

Props like `label`, `title`, or `description` came from SelectInput. How can I add type to StyledField, so I accepts the props that are aceped by SelectInput?

I've tried to add this:

styled(Field)

which are props from SelectInput but got this error:

```
Type 'SelectInputT' does not satisfy the constraint '"symbol" | "object" | "data" | "form" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "body" | "br" | "button" | ... 154 more ... | "view"'.
  Type 'SelectInputT' is not assignable to type '"view"'. [2344]
```

I've also tried:

```
styled<PropsWithChildren<SelectInputT>>(Field)
```

but got a similar error

**EDIT:**

Here is a Minimal Reproducible Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-field-redux-form-mtgu8y?file=/src/App.tsx

After creating minimal example, I've tried to experiment with `PropsWithChildren<WrappedFieldProps>` but with no effect:

```
styled<PropsWithChildren<WrappedFieldProps> & SelectInputT>(Field)

styled<PropsWithChildren<WrappedFieldProps & SelectInputT>>(Field)
```

Comment: Could you prepare a minimal reproducible example (codesandbox)?
The issue might be related to the `Field` component itself.

Comment: @BartKrakowski added repro to Codesanbox

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectInput` component have to implement the `WrappedFieldProps` interface.
You can simply implement this interface to the `SelectInput` component:

```
const SelectInput = ({ input }: WrappedFieldProps) => {
  return <p>{input.name}</p>;
};
```

If you'd like to add your own props to this component, you can simply extend this interface

```
interface SelectInputT extends WrappedFieldProps {
  yourExtraProp: any
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-field-redux-form-forked-empqhz?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Your second code doesn't work, or maybe I do something wrong https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-field-redux-form-forked-8b4rv7?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Note that you can't pass the `options` prop to the `StyledField` component, because `StyledField` is a styled Field (from redux-form), not your own component.
Making the new custom props optional makes it work, but IDK if this is the expected result due to what I wrote above.

Comment: If I replace styledField with Field it works. I can use custom props but not with style components.

Comment: Not quite. You'd have to pass all required props from this interface: `WrappedFieldProps`.
https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-field-redux-form-forked-8b4rv7?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Can you elaborate? You just copy-pasted my code sandbox.